# Can we spin up a scalable application server using aws ecs ? I mean like a ec2 instnace with amazon linux ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to know the possibility of having a application server (linux machine) spinned up using ecs ?

I.e An Ec2 instance running an application which serves user requests .

To be more clear.. can we spin up a ec2 via a container ?

Comment: You can launch new instance programmatically https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/run-instance.html

Comment: EC2 instances are not containers. You can spin up an EC2 instance using EC2 but not using Elastic Container Service because it's not a container.